# Use eig and svd syntax in matlab to find complex eigenvalues of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matlab

For matrix $A= \left( \begin{array}{c}
1 & 1  \\
-1 & 1   \\
 \end{array} \right) $ when I calculate the eigenvalues (without matlab) , I find $\lambda_1=1+1i$ and $\lambda_1=1-1i$ and when I use $eig$ syntax in matlab again the  eigenvalues are $\lambda_1=1+1i$ and $\lambda_1=1-1i$ but when I use $svd$ syntax in matlab (singular value decomposition)  I mean $A=U\Lambda V^H$  diagonal elements of matrix $\Lambda$ are not $1+1i$ and $1-1i$ now I'm confused and I don't know why diagonal elements of matrix $\Lambda$ are not $1+1i$ and $1-1i$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Singular values` are not `eigenvalues`, you can refer to the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value).